# Owl Carousel - Skips Past Images using Prev / Next

Tags: javascript, slider, wordpress-theming, owl-carousel

Our custom Owl Carousel isn't behaving as expected - while dragging and using keyboard arrows takes you to the next slide, the previous and next arrows jump 'over' the next slide to the one after.

The next slide does appear briefly but quickly flicks to the following slide.

I've tried a few things in the main.js settings but no dice. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated as I'm a bit stumped.

main.js code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// initialise owl
  $(function() {
      var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
      owl.owlCarousel({
      items:1,
      lazyLoad:true,
      loop:true,
      useMouseWheel: false,
      nav: true,
      center: true,
      dots: false,
      margin: 0,
      stagePadding: 0,
      URLhashListener: true,
      startPosition: 'URLHash',
      animateIn: 'fadeIn',
      animateOut: 'fadeOut'
    });

    // click for next image
    $(owl).click(function() {
      owl.trigger('next.owl');
    })

      // add arrow keys to carousel navigation
      $(document).on('keydown', function( event ) { //attach event listener
        if(event.keyCode == 37) {
          owl.trigger('prev.owl')
        }
        if(event.keyCode == 39) {
          owl.trigger('next.owl')
          }
      });
      // end arrow keys



  }); // end owl


}); // end document ready
```

Happy to share any other parts of the code if it would be useful. Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: I reckon what is happening is that two click events are being fired. Notice when you click on the image (The $('.owl-carousel') elem) it fires once. But when you click on either arrow, you are triggering the click event you created as well as the library's click event. Hence it fires twice. You will need to define what you are clicking on, and then fire either the next or previous trigger. Let me know how you get on. :)

Comment: Thanks Tiberiuscan - I noticed that (arrow keystrokes also work like they should). The navigation arrows are activated by a boolean setting as per the code above, so I'm not sure how to define what the user is clicking on like you suggest (I'm still trying to wrap my head around js)

Comment: I will take a look at it tomorrow but if you were to comment out your click function do the arrows work? If so then my initial comment proves the issue is to do with the click bindings.

Comment: @Tiberiuscan - you are dead right - commented out the click function and the nav arrows work as they should. So any clue what would I do to get both working in unison? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Tiberiuscan pointing me in the right direction, I figured out a solution:

The click for next image part was targeting the entire owl carousel for clicks.

I modified this code to target the owl-item div and that resolved the issue, as below:

```
      // click for next image
  $('.owl-item').click(function() {
    owl.trigger('next.owl');
  })
```

Thanks again, @Tiberiuscan

Comment: No problem @Mike, I can see it working now with your code. Nice one.